# Pyspark: Filter DF based on columns, then run every subset DF through a function

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark and am a bit confused on how to think of the problem.

I have a large dataframe and I would like to filter down every subset of that dataframe based on two columns and run it through the same algorithm.

Here is an example of how I run it (extremely inefficiently) now:

```
for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    for number in [1, 2, 3]
        filtered_DF_1, filtered_DF_2 = filter_func(DF_1, DF_2, letter, number)
        process_function(filtered_DF_1, filtered_DF_2)
```

Basic filter function:

```
def filter_func(DF_1, DF_2, letter, number):

    DF_1 = DF_1.filter(
        (F.col("Letter") == letter) &                                
        (F.col('Number') == number)                          
    )

    DF_2 = DF_2.filter(
        (F.col("Letter") == letter) &                                
        (F.col('Number') == number)                         
    )

    return DF_1, DF_2
```

Since this is Pyspark, I would like to parallelize it, since each iteration of the function can run independently.

Do I need to do some sort of mapping to get all my data subsets?
And then do I need to do anything to the `process_function` to make it available to all nodes as well to run and return an answer?

What is the best way to do this? 
​
EDIT:

The `process_function` takes the filtered dataset and runs it through about 7 different functions that are already written in 300 lines of pyspark --> the end goal is to return a list of timestamps that are overbooked based on a bunch of complicated logic.

I think my plan is to build a dictionary of letter --> [number], then explode that list to get every permutation and create a dataset from that. Then map through that, and hopefully am able to create a udf for my process_function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry a lot about parallelizing or the execution plan because the spark catalyst does it in the background for you. Also better to avoid UDF, you can do it mostly with inbulit function.
Are you doing a transformation function or an aggregate function inside you process_func?

Please provide any test data and suitable example of expected output. That would help in better answering..